# SQL - Separate string based on 'in between Nth and Nth delimiter'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ITEM table with an ITEM column. They are all one string. Some example products in this column may be:

```
AAA-BBB-CCC.B.S
AAA-BBB-CCC.B.M
BAA-123A-DDDD.01.28
BAA-123A-DDDD.20.28
CCC-AACD-CCDD.MB.28.L
CCC-AACD-CCDD.MB.29.L
CCC-AACD-CCDD.FC.28.R
CCC-AACD-CCDD.FC.29.R
```

- The first 3 parts (separated by hyphens) is the product code
- Anything in between the 1st and 2nd period is the **colour**
- Anything after the 2nd period but before the 3rd period (if a 3rd period is actually present) is the **item size**
- If there is a 3rd period present, anything after it is the **item fit** (e.g. Jeans with S/R/L leg length)

I'd like to separate these elements into separate columns, but I'm struggling due to the "not always present" item fit attribute, as well as the "after x but before y" nature of trying to get the data separated. I've got the below so far, which gets the item size, but if there's a fit present then it gets that instead, which makes it not very useful.

This is in SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

```
SELECT ITEM
,RIGHT(ITEM, CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(ITEM)) -1) 'Size'
FROM ITEM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to parse and create columns.  However, you lost me on which element was what.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Item varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'AAA-BBB-CCC.B.S'),
(2,'AAA-BBB-CCC.B.M'),
(3,'BAA-123A-DDDD.01.28'),
(4,'BAA-123A-DDDD.20.28'),
(5,'CCC-AACD-CCDD.MB.28.L'),
(6,'CCC-AACD-CCDD.MB.29.L'),
(7,'CCC-AACD-CCDD.FC.28.R'),
(8,'CCC-AACD-CCDD.FC.29.R')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.Item,'.','-'),'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: @Smeghead Happy it helped

Comment: Sorry, I've come across another road bump with this data.

We also have things like shirts and shoes which have half sizes, and annoyingly these are also split by a period, but the end is not the fit, e.g [AAA-BBB-CCC.BLK.16.5] would be a size '16.5' shirt.

Is there any way to conditionally split it, so "IF I.ITEM LIKE '%.%.%.5' split to 5 columns, ELSE split to 6 columns"?

I tried using 2 OUTER APPLY statements for the 2 scenarios, but the ones to split into 5 columns just returned NULL in those columns.

Comment: @Smeghead I trust you've gathered that you can easily expand the number of columns , but regarding the .5,  there are many possible solutions.  For example replace .5 with a special character or token like *5